# Display differences of SSRS reports in IE and CHROME

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which runs both on IE and Chrome. In `IE` its design is just fine, just as it looked during preview in SSDT (when I toggle + buttton on Textbox1, Textbox2 position doesn't move):

[image]

However, in `Chrome,` when I toggle + button, textbox2 moves to the right
[image]

How to make so that Textbox2 doesn't change position, or, as alternative, force STAT NAME field to wrap text as in IE?

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening. I do know that earlier versions of SSRS are optimized for IE. I believe SSRS 2016 works basically the same across multiple internet platforms.

Comment: Chrome is not full supported by SSRS 2012 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.110).aspx). I'm not sure if this extension can help you but you can try it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-fix/gklhehemnkbjbccoeneabopaflildkah/reviews .
Whatever, you can share the html/css code and maybe will be possible apply some css hack for fix it